# How can I calculate these large exponents with mods?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Is there a fast technique that I can use that is similar in each case to calculate the following:

$$(1100)^{1357} \mod{2623} = 1519$$

$$(1819)^{1357} \mod{2623} = 2124$$

$$(0200)^{1357} \mod{2623} = 2227$$

$$(1111)^{1357} \mod{2623} = 1111$$

I used Wolfram Alpha to get to these answers, but I would like to know how to calculate it by hand (with a standard pocket calculator).

Comment: If not even a pocket calculator is allowed, it will be extremely tedious and you will almost certainly make a computation error anyway.

Comment: The method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) is reasonably "fast". You'll still have to do dozens of multiplications by hand.

Comment: @fkraiem A pocket calculator is fine. I will add it to my question.

Comment: Related: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Carmichael theorem. This theorem states that $$a^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$$

if $\gcd(a,2623)=1$. In this case we have $\lambda(2623)=\mathrm{lcm}(42,60)=420$.

Therefore, if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $$a^{1357} \equiv a^{1357-1260} = a^{97} \mod 2623$$

This is more friendly to compute with the method @Mauris describes.

Answer (score 3):

I would follow the pseudocode given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method):

- Write your exponent, 1357, in binary: $10101001101_2$.
- Let $b := x\mod 2623$.
- Let $r := 1$.
- Step through the bits from right-to left:

  - If the bit is $1$:

    - Let $r := b \cdot r \mod 2623$.
  - Let $b := b^2 \mod 2623$.

Then $r$ will be your final result. This requires 17 multiplications modulo $2623$. In general it requires (number of 1-bits) + (number of bits) multiplications.

(To compute a "modulo" operation on a pocket calculator, you can either subtract $2623$ repeatedly until you get a result that's less than $2623$, or you can calculate $x - \lfloor x / 2623 \rfloor \cdot 2623$.)

**EDIT**: You can use the Carmichael theorem to reduce the exponent to 97, as [@wythagoras](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367592/141424) explains. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Factorize $2623=43\times 61$.
Remember the [Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which tells you that

$$a^{\phi(n)}=1\mod n$$
if $n$ and $a$ are coprime. For prime $n$, you have $\phi(n)=n-1$.

You can also use the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: How do you combine the results? $1111^{1357} \equiv 36 \pmod{43}$ and $1111^{1357} \equiv 13 \pmod{61}$ -- how do you get from those two numbers to $1111$?

Comment: The solution is in the form that satisfies $x=36+43n=13+61m$ for integers $n$, $m$. This is a linear diophantine equation that can be solved with standard algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Combine Little Fermat and Cinese remainder theorem: as $2623=43\cdot61$, we have:
$$\mathbf Z/2623\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/43\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/61\mathbf Z.$$
To compute, say, $1100^{1357}\bmod 2623$, you first compute $1100\bmod 43=25$ and $1100\bmod61=2$. Then use Little Fermat for each of the congruences:
$$\begin{cases}
1100^{1357}\equiv 25^{1357\bmod42}=25^{13}\equiv 14\mod 43\\
1100^{1357}\equiv 2^{1357\bmod60}=2^{37}\equiv 55\equiv-6\mod 61
\end{cases}$$
(the powers can be computed with fast exponentiation, by successive squarings).

Now we have to go back to $\mathbf Z/2623\mathbf Z$. From the Bézout relation:
$\;12\cdot61-17\cdot43=1\;$ (obtained from the *extended euclidean algorithm*, we obtain:
$$1100^{1357}\equiv 12\cdot14\cdot61-17\cdot55\cdot43\equiv1819\mod 2623.$$